# Looping all values received in laravel $request

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, parameters, request

My form has multiple check boxes where there names also change page to page. Something like below code.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="name01" value="10">
 <input type="checkbox" name="name08" value="15"
```

Just imagine there are 20 check-boxes . If someone check 10 check-boxes I want them to be inserted in to DB using a `foreach` loop . So what I have done so far is

```
foreach($request as $singleItem){

        //Looping to check the name 
        for($I=0 ;$I<25;$I++){

        //Making the name
            $name = 'item'.$I;

        if($singleItem[$name] ){

            $values[] = [
                'value' => $singleItem[$name]
            ];
        }
        }
    }
    dd($values);
```

But this gives me below error

[image: error]

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fetch it like,

```
$arr = $request->all();
dd($arr);
foreach($arr as $key => $singleItem){
// $key is your name01, name02, etc
// here you will get padded name string if you want to check.
$name = str_pad($key, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if(isset($arr[$name])){
        $values[] = [
                'value' => $singleItem
        ];
    }
}
```